# Generating unique random numbers

Tags: clojure

I want to make my own `rand-nth` that only takes each element in vector once and when there are no more unique numbers to generate it throws an exception.
The only way I can think of doing this is through recursion but it is not working as I want, first of it needs a number n for how many times to recur which is not how rand-nth works. 
This is the code I have so far but it will not do what I want. 
(this code selects random cards from a vector called deck containing 52 cards)

```
(defn random-card-seq
  "Generate n number of random cards from deck"
  [n]
  (loop [cnt n
         cards []
         new-deck deck]
    (if (zero? cnt)
      cards
      (recur (dec cnt) (conj cards (rand-nth deck)) (pop random from dec HOW TO CREATE NEW DECK) ))))
```

Im thinking something with memorization and repeatedly would work but don't know how to.

Comment: I think you might want to be calling `rand-nth new-deck` not `rand-nth deck`.

Answer (score 1):

[Shuffle](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/shuffle) will help you do what you want:

```
(defn n-random-elements
  [n deck]
  (take n (shuffle deck)))
```

Comment: Yes but i would like to make my own pure clojure implementation. Shuffle uses javainterop exclusively.

Comment: @user3139545 It is a Clojure principle to use Java directly wherever it can. Why do you wish to do otherwise?